# Paging toolbar not display second page

Tags: javascript, extjs

When I click button next on paging toolbar store started to load and data for second page appear and at once disappear.
When I looked in network I have seen two requests: first correct for second page and second not correct, it overwrite data for second page.

**Screenshot of network tab**

[image]

**My model:**

```
Ext.define('Admin.view.items.ItemsModel', {
    id: 'ItemsModel',
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
    alias: 'viewmodel.items',
    requires: [
        'Admin.proxy.API'
    ],
    stores: {
        storeItemsAll: {
            type: 'store',
            autoLoad: true,
            autoDestory: true,
            disableCaching: false,
            proxy: {
                type: 'api',
                url: SITE_URL + '/api/items',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    rootProperty: 'data',
                    totalProperty: 'total'
                }
            },
            fields: [{
                type: 'string',
                name: 'id'
            }, {
                type: 'string',
                name: 'name'
            }, {
                type: 'string',
                name: 'updated_at'
            }, {
                type: 'string',
                name: 'created_at'
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

**My paging toolbar:**

```
bbar: {
    id: 'ItemsPaginator',
    xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
    displayInfo: true,
    bind: {
        store: '{storeItemsAll}'
    }
}
```

> **My grid code:**

```
Ext.define('Admin.view.items.ItemsTable', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    xtype: 'items-table',
    requires: [
        'Ext.grid.Panel',
        'Ext.grid.View'
    ],
    title: __('items_details_h1'),
    height: 'fit',
    bodyPadding: 15,
    layout: {
        type: 'vbox',
        align: 'stretch'
    },
    items: [{
        xtype: 'container',
        layout: 'fit',
        items: [{
            id: 'ItemsTable',
            xtype: 'gridpanel',
            userCls: 'ypoints-list',
            header: false,
            title: __('wizard_items_added'),
            hideHeaders: false,
            scrollable: {
                x: false,
                y: true
            },
            bind: {
                store: '{storeItemsAll}'
            },
            viewConfig: {
                getRowClass: function(record, rowIndex, rowParams, store) {
                    return 'ypoint-row';
                },
                emptyText: __('no_data'),
                deferEmptyText: false
            },
            rootVisible: false,
            dockedItems: [{
                dock: 'top',
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'container',
                    userCls: 'ypoints-btns',
                    items: [{
                        xtype: 'button',
                        height: 35,
                        text: __('items_add'),
                        userCls: 'ypoints-btn',
                        handler: 'onItemAdd'
                    }]
                }]
            }],
            bbar: {
                id: 'ItemPaginator',
                xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
                displayInfo: true,
                bind: {
                    store: '{storeItemsAll}'
                }
            },
            columns: [{
                text: __('item_name_field'),
                dataIndex: 'name',
                sortable: true,
                flex: 1
            }, {
                text: __('item_updated_at_field'),
                dataIndex: 'updated_at',
                sortable: true,
                flex: 1
            }, {
                text: __('item_created_at_field'),
                dataIndex: 'created_at',
                sortable: true,
                flex: 1
            }, {
                xtype: 'actioncolumn',
                header: __('actions_field'),
                flex: 1,
                items: [{
                    iconCls: 'x-fa fa-pencil-square-o',
                    tooltip: __('edit_item'),
                    handler: 'onItemEdit'
                }, {
                    iconCls: 'x-fa fa-trash',
                    tooltip: __('remove_item'),
                    handler: 'onItemRemove'
                }, {
                    iconCls: 'x-fa fa-eye',
                    tooltip: __('preview_item'),
                    handler: 'onItemPreview'
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }]
});
```

Comment: provide your grid code because as you mentioned code is working fine you can visit with this **[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2fvp)**

Comment: I am added code of my grid. Look please